# SQL Server 2014 query into specific XML format

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have been asked to provide some data in XML format to a 3rd party company. I am using SQL Server 2014 for this. I cannot find anything anywhere which relates to the format that has been requested.

The format is as follows:

```
<Item>
    <p:attribute_name="Product">Coat</p:attribute>
    <p:attribute_name="Colour">Purple</p:attribute>
    <p:attribute_name="Material">Polyester, Nylon</p:attribute>
</Item>
```

The SQL code to get this is:

```
SELECT
    Product,
    Colour,
    Material
FROM Products
```

Which returns this:

```
ID    Product    Colour    Material
1     Coat       Purple    Polyester, Nylon
```

I would like to know if it is at all possible to return the results of the query into the XML format provided.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you need to unpivot the data first and then generate the XML.

Comment: The XML you state as target format is not valid... I suppose it's `<p:attribute name="Product">Coat</p:attribute>`. And there seem to be a namespace "p" which is not declared...

Comment: `attribute_name` should probably be `attribute name` (the element name is `attribute`, the attribute name is `name`). `p:` is a prefix for a namespace that hasn't been declared. If you're adapting this format from the actual format, maybe you shouldn't do that and just give us the actual format. What you want is undoubtedly possible through judicious use of [`FOR XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178107), specifically [`FOR XML PATH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb510462), but you'll need to pay attention to the specifics.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, no need tp unpivot... `FOR XML PATH` can put identical elements one after the other, if you separate them with an "empty" node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment, your target format is not valid and a namespace is missing. My magic glass bulb tells me, that you are looking for something like this:

#### EDIT: Sorry, my first code mixed the captions!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(ID INT,Product VARCHAR(100),Colour VARCHAR(100),Material VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES(1,'Coat','Purple','Polyester,Nylon');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('test' AS p)
SELECT 'Product' AS [p:attributName/@name]
      ,Product AS [p:attributName]
      ,''
      ,'Colour' AS [p:attributName/@name]
      ,Colour AS [p:attributName]
      ,''
      ,'Material' AS [p:attributName/@name]
      ,Material AS [p:attributName]
FROM dbo.Test
FOR XML PATH('Item')

DROP TABLE dbo.Test;

/*
<Item xmlns:p="test">
  <p:attributName name="Product">Coat</p:attributName>
  <p:attributName name="Colour">Purple</p:attributName>
  <p:attributName name="Material">Polyester,Nylon</p:attributName>
</Item>
*/
```

Comment: This is spot on for what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    Product VARCHAR(50),
    Colour VARCHAR(50),
    Material VARCHAR(150)
)
INSERT INTO @t (Product, Colour, Material)
VALUES
    ('Coat', 'Purple', 'Polyester, Nylo'),
    ('test', 'test2', 'test3')

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('p' as p)
SELECT ID, val
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT val = (
        SELECT
            [@name] = t2.id,
            [text()] = t2.[value]
        FROM (
            VALUES
                ('Product', Product),
                ('Colour', Colour),
                ('Material', Material)
        ) t2 (id, value)
        FOR XML PATH('p:attribute'), ROOT('Item'), TYPE
    )
) t2
```